# How do I determine SFDC Edition using SOQL?

Tags: soql

How do I use SOQL to determine what edition of SFDC someone has? Such as essential, professional, etc...

Comment: By the way, this may be [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It is generally advisable to use feature detection whenever possible, as there are many features that can be enabled independently of edition (sometimes as an extra cost, or for other reasons).

Answer (score 2):

You can either check via the steps mentioned in this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334996&type=1&mode=1) or use the below soql:

```
SELECT Id, OrganizationType FROM Organization
```